# Advance allotment of a primary key in a SQL Server table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, primary-key, msmq

I have a database table `Contact`, in my application layer I'm getting a request from the client (i.e., Web API HTTP request) and I'm pushing the data into MSMQ.

I also have a Windows Service which receives the message from the respective MSMQ and processes the data. It inserts the data into the respective database table `Contact`.

SQL Server table structure of `Contact`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact] 
(
    [ContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](10),
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Contact PRIMARY KEY (ContactId)
)
```

In this process, I need to send the primary key of the table `Contact` because the primary key is the `Id` of `Contact`. In the response, the client expects the `Contact Id`.

It is possible to allot an `Id` of `Contact` before data is inserted? or kindly assist me.

Please let me know changes required in the table structure.

Comment: _" I need to send the Primary Key of the table "Contact""_ send it where? And when is it sent?

Comment: The field ContactID is identity and autonumeric. You want to insert a speficic value for that field partially disablign the autonumeric?

Comment: As far as getting the ID, isn´t it the same to insert and then get the ContactID recently inserted?.

Comment: So, your question is basically how to get back the identity value that was generated by your insert statement?

Comment: No, his problem is he want to know next id available i.e. 3 and show it before doing the insert in his wondow. Then when he save he wants to save it with that id. the problem is that another application could have taken the place

Comment: I think he wants to get ID before SQL insert and before any SQL query. Maybe use GUID for primary ID?

Comment: @VikciaR - I can't change the datatype. It's in remote, I don't have the permission moreover most of the developers used the same. Right-now It's very costliest operation to change.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan: But how do you manage to get id before sql connection, if your ID will be born on insert?

Comment: You cant know the next Id before its inserted, you could guess (previous Id + 1) but it will be prone to error.

Comment: @jamiec no you can't but you can cheat it

Comment: I'ts impossible to know the value that will be assigned to an identity column **before** the insert. and since the table structure can't be changed, the only thing left is to get the inserted value back from the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use GUID.

1. Generate GUID and pass it to INSERT.
2. Use this GUID for primary key, or use guid to get Id AFTER insert (Add additional column, then later you could get row by this column).

Comment: I need to return back a **READABLE ID** not a Guid.

Comment: First: you can't have Id BEFORE you insert, when it is identity. Next: you can't have Id before you connect to database - unless it is GUID or other unique identificator (if you can connect before insert, then you can use SEQUENCE and make reservation before insert). Next: GUID is pretty readable :-) I suggested in my answer you to use temporary id or job key - guid (because it is unique system wide), and after insert to get real Id. So your job would be in two steps: insert and then acquire Id.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple sessions running you can't use built-in functions to get the next id available but you can work around that.

The work around is quite simple. here's are the step

1 - create another table with :

```
contactid, integer, identity same as yours
id, guid
isUsed, bit, default 0
```

2 - generate for each application that is running a guid when it starts

3 - when ready to create a contact in your window query the new table where the id is equal to your generated guid and where the isUsed is false, if there is any take that Contactid as it's not used yet, otherwise insert a new record in that table with your guid and isused as false and query again. this will generate a id just for your session.

4 - remove the identity on the contact table as id will come from the other table with identity and those are unique so no clashing possible

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know which will be the next identity value, there is a built-in function for that. Nevertheless doing what you are suppposed to do is not recomended because other sessions may insert in that table. You may want to use other method of creating a numeric ID for your table, or just insert some data to "allot" and the updating with your real values. It seems a lot of work and I would recomend to insert the data and then getting the real ID with SCOPE_IDENTITY() function. That would be much secure.

Anyway, here is the function that will return that next autonumeric value:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Contact') + 1
```

Comment: Consider, I'm receiving 100 Request form different client then think the result...

Comment: then this solution is not for you

Comment: why don´t you insert and then get the identity. Isn´t that possible?}

Comment: @NicoRiff - Windows Service is a different project. So, I can't. My job is just validate the in-coming data and if the data is valid, push the same into the MSMQ.